# Loading a view with the keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard

How could I load the view and load the keyboard so it is ready to type in a single text field.

The textfield is called textField and I know i must call this when the view is loaded, but cannot get my head round how.

I have shopped around for an answer, but Stack Overflow cannot provide a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to set that text field as first responder? 
[textField becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: where would I place that code, I have tried that, but no where works... thanks btw :)

Comment: if you want to make it appear just after the view is shown, I would go for viewDidApear. it will be called always when the view appears, if that is what you want.

Comment: If you want to happen only first time, then viewDidLoad will be perfect.